# Is throughput in the mapreduce metrics in MB or Mb

Tags: hadoop

After running TestDFSIO I got the following metrics:

```
2019-04-30 09:50:35,790 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:             Date & time: Tue Apr 30 09:50:35 EDT 2019
2019-04-30 09:50:35,791 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:         Number of files: 100
2019-04-30 09:50:35,791 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:  Total MBytes processed: 10000
2019-04-30 09:50:35,791 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:       Throughput mb/sec: 376.9
2019-04-30 09:50:35,791 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:  Average IO rate mb/sec: 387.16
2019-04-30 09:50:35,791 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:   IO rate std deviation: 60.42
2019-04-30 09:50:35,791 INFO fs.TestDFSIO:      Test exec time sec: 115.21
```

Is `Average IO rate mb/sec` in MegaByte or Megabits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TestDFSIO` is a usefult tool but the only available documentation is in its source code.

By looking at the code for `TestDFSIO.java` it seems that the throughput is expressed in Mebibytes per seconds.

In the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/TestDFSIO.java) one can see how troughput is computed:

```
"      Throughput mb/sec: " + df.format(toMB(size) / msToSecs(time)),
```

Function `toMB()` is the number of bytes divided by MEGA:

```
static float toMB(long bytes) {
    return ((float)bytes)/MEGA;
  }
```

which is in turn the constant `0x100000L`, that is the integer 1048576=1024*1024.

From the code:

```
private static final long MEGA = ByteMultiple.MB.value();
```

and

```
enum ByteMultiple {
    B(1L),
    KB(0x400L),
    MB(0x100000L),
    GB(0x40000000L),
    TB(0x10000000000L);
   ...
```

So the throughput should be expressed in mebibytes/sec (MiB/sec) and not in megabytes (MB).

Comment: Is the throughput given per file or for the whole task?

Comment: @user9332151 it's computed for the whole task, quote: "throughput in mb/sec (total number of bytes / sum of processing times)"